# Xamarin Studio Does Not Recognize Android SDK Path

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin-studio, android-sdk-2.3

I have installed Xamarin Studio
[image]

And I have also downloaded Android SDK
[image]

But when I run Xamarin Studio and try to create a new android app it tells me android sdk path is not set. so I proceed to set it
[image]

But as you can see it does not accept the path. This is the contents of android-sdk folder
[image]

and this is the sdk manager application screenshot in which there is nothing to download
[image]

What should I do?
I have searched all the similar questions but all in vain please do not mark this question as duplicate before you read the other questions and their answers. Thanks

Comment: Not sure exactly why but it seems that you are missing platform tools. Xamarin Studio on Windows checks for that the file Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe exists inside Program Files. From your screenshot that directory is missing. Also your Android SDK Manager window seems to be missing a lot of packages. I would try restarting the Android SDK Manager window and maybe set the Force check box in Options in the Android manager.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First:** Your Android sdk is missing a lot of stuff. it is not complete.
You can download complete android sdk from [Here](http://go.puresoftware.org/android-sdk-windows-zip)

**Second:** Xamarin uses .Net to create android and ios apps. In order to convert C# codes to Java codes Xamarin needs android Native Development Tools. You can download it from [Here](http://pub.fileniko.com//f/2015/02/Android.NDK.r10d.win.x86.www.fileniko.com.rar) as well.

**NOTE:** These links are for those who can not access android.google.com due to political restrictions otherwise I strongly RECOMMEND to download both [SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) and [NDK](http://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/index.html) from Google.